# Googlesheet urlFetchapp find value regex

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get the decimal value "Equity" from this website link https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/1412566

refer to image what value i want to scrape.
[need scrape Equity value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZqub.jpg)

i wrote appscript to scrape data

```
function getEquity(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText()
  
  var data = source.match(/<div class="s-list-info__value">([\d.]*).*<\/div>/)[1];
  console.log(data);
  return (data)
}
getEquity("https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/1412566");
```

but it take wrong value instead . so how could i adjust code to get "Equity" value.

thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```
function getEquity(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();
  var data = [...source.matchAll(/<div class="s-list-info__value">([\d.]*).*<\/div>/g)][2][1]; // Modified
  console.log(data);
  return (data)
}
```

Or

```
function getEquity(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();
  var data = source.match(/<div class\="s-list-info__label">Equity: <\/div>[\w\s]+?<div class="s-list-info__value">([\d.]*).*<\/div>/)[1]; // Modified
  console.log(data);
  return (data)
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- In this case, when the specification of HTML is changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

Comment: `var data = [...source.matchAll(/<div class="s-list-info__value">([\d.]*).*<\/div>/g)][2][1]; // Modified`

could you explain what does 3 dot "...source" did ? thanks

Comment: @ammar ibrahim It's the spread syntax. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) For example, that is the same with `var data = Array.from(source.matchAll(/<div class="s-list-info__value">([\d.]*).*<\/div>/g))[2][1];`.